# Сделать расширенную электронную коммерцию

Tags: google-analytics, yandex-metrika-api

Надо настроить расширенную электронную коммерцию через TGM для YM и GA

0) dataEcommerce в такой форме 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1) Передаю в TGM массив $data//dataEcommerce

```
<script>dataEcommerce = [<?=json_encode($data)?>];</script>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=<?=Configure::read('GoogleTagManager')?>"
                      height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataEcommerce','<?=Configure::read('GoogleTagManager')?>');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

2) Tag для YM настроил так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (d, w, c) {
        (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() {
            try {
                w.yaCounter32547095 = new Ya.Metrika({
                    id:32547095,
                    clickmap:true,
                    trackLinks:true,
                    accurateTrackBounce:true,
                    ecommerce: 'dataEcommerce'
                });
            } catch(e) { }
        });

        var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
            s = d.createElement("script"),
            f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); };
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.async = true;
        s.src="https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";

        if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
            d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
        } else { f(); }
    })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");
</script>
<noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/32547095" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
<!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
```

3) для GA tag настроил так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4) теги отрабатывают на странице
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не в YM не в GA не падают заказы

Comment: В YM начало падать. Убрал подключения счетчика на YM

Comment: Перенастроил tag для GA в соответствие со статьей (https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en) и в GA стало падать